# Problema de agregación en una matriz en Power BI - Cálculo de importe en varios niveles jerárquicos

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, data, dax

Estoy teniendo un problema con una matriz en Power BI que involucra una serie de tablas y relaciones complejas. Intentaré explicar la situación de la manera más clara posible.

Estructura de datos y relaciones:

FactDiariComptable: Esta es mi tabla de hechos que contiene varias columnas, incluyendo Cuenta, Importe, Centro de Coste, Material y Proveedor. Algunas transacciones tienen valores en todos estos campos, mientras que otras solo en algunos.

PlanContable: Esta es una tabla de todas las cuentas que existen y sus distintos niveles de agregación. Está relacionada con FactDiariComptable.

xtr VW_DimJerarquia: Esta tabla tiene cuatro columnas - Cuenta, Relación (que es un código para Centro de Coste, Material o Proveedor), Grupo (que especifica si el código se refiere a un Proveedor, Material o Centro de Coste) y Descripción. Esta tabla muestra todas las combinaciones posibles de Cuenta, Relación, Grupo y Descripción que existen en FactDiariComptable.

Objetivo:

Mi objetivo es mostrar en una matriz los datos agregados por varios niveles: Niveles de Cuenta, Grupo y Descripción. Quiero expandir el nivel de Cuenta y ver el importe asociado con cada Grupo dentro de esa Cuenta y, a su vez, expandir cada Grupo y ver el importe asociado con cada Descripción dentro de ese Grupo.

Problema:

Estoy usando la siguiente medida en mi matriz:

```
Prueba = 
VAR impcal = CALCULATE(
        [Importe],
        FILTER(
            'FactDiariComptable',
            'FactDiariComptable'[Cuenta] = max('xtr VW_DimJerarquia'[Compte])
                && COALESCE('FactDiariComptable'[Ce.Coste], 'FactDiariComptable'[Proveedor], 'FactDiariComptable'[Material]) 
                   = min('xtr VW_DimJerarquia'[Relació])
        )
    )

return 
IF (impcal <> 0, impcal, [Importe])
```

Sin embargo, estoy obteniendo resultados incorrectos en el nivel de Descripción. Cuando llego al nivel de Cuenta, la suma total del importe no coincide con la suma de los importes en el nivel de Descripción. Por ejemplo, para la cuenta contable 21610000, el importe total es de 1500, pero cuando expandimos para ver los detalles de los proveedores dentro de esa cuenta, vemos que uno tiene un importe de 1500 y el otro tiene un importe de 400. Por lo tanto, el total debería ser 1900, no 1500.

He notado que si cambio MAX por MIN en la medida, el importe mostrado se invierte.

Pregunta:

¿Cómo puedo modificar mi medida para que el importe total a nivel de Cuenta sea la suma de los importes a nivel de Descripción? Es decir, ¿cómo puedo hacer que la suma del importe se muestre correctamente en todos los niveles de la matriz (Cuenta, Grupo, Descripción), asegurándome de que los importes se agreguen correctamente en cada nivel jerárquico? Cualquier ayuda para entender y resolver este problema sería muy apreciada.

Muchas gracias de antemano por su tiempo y asistencia.

Comment: ¿no funciona `sum()`?